# force headphone mode

Tags: audio, headphones, headphone-jack

When I plug in the 3.5mm jack and play back media, headphone mode keeps toggling, resulting in audio cutting in/ out every second or so.
Is there a way to force headphone mode or disable the 3.5mm jack detection?

I tried a couple of apps and searched the web but people seem to want to force speakers rather than headphones, so no luck.

(Android 4.2.2 Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite)

Answer (score -1):

First off, you require root. Then Install Xposed Framework and Install an app ( forgot the name but do a quick google search for it and you will find it ) which lets you override your deafult actions when certain things happen like  plugging in the headphone. Then you can set that action to anything you want.